# IntelliJ Compiling error with gRPC

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, grpc, gatling

IntelliJ tells this compiling error, when I build a scala project to test gRPC APIs with Gatling.

IntelliJ:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4674.33, built on March 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Scala Plugin

```
Version: 2017.3.15
```

The project depends on another project(API). The latter one uses the following pom file (gRPC).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```
  val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
      .forAddress("...", 8088)
      .usePlaintext(true)
      .build()   // <---- IntelliJ says "Error:..." here
```

Error:

```
Error:(10, 161) value build is not a member of ?0
  val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("...", 8088).usePlaintext(true).build()
```

I cannot see anything wrong with the code. Is it a bug of IntelliJ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the project build from the command line with Maven?

Comment: @Justin, I used IntelliJ's "Rebuild Project", which is convenient. Upon your suggestion, I found there was no problem with the command line. I followed the link given by Eric, and solved the problem by adding an extra line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue was a bug in Scala that was fixed in Scala 2.11 and later. See [grpc-java issue 2813](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2813) for discussion.

Comment: Thank you. IntelliJ use Scala 2.12. But I fixed the problem by adding an extra line mentioned in the link.